# No wso2server.sh for the wso2-iot service

Tags: linux, wso2, wso2-iot

I have installed the wso2iot-3.1.0 on a linux distribution (debian 9).

To create services for the three modules (broker, iot and analytics) I followed this documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service

No problem for the broker and analytics services, I found the file wso2server.sh in their respective directories :

- wso2iot-3.1.0/wso2/analytics/bin/wso2server.sh

  wso2iot-3.1.0/wso2/broker/bin/wso2server.sh

But I can't find the wso2server.sh to launch iot as a service.
Did someone experienced this problem or have a solution ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WSO2 IoT 3.1.0 onwards, we are using iot-server.sh file in IoT_HOME/bin folder to start the server. This was done due to refactoring in IoT core level to conform with the new product structure. Other two servers (broker and analytics) will undergo the same in a future release.